# What is the species of Gellert Grindelwald's pet?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, magical-creatures, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*, at the beginning of the movie we see some sort of creature living in the prison cell with Grindelwald. It has a long, sticky tongue like a frog and roughly the size of a small cat. During his initial escape he calms and comforts it before throwing it out the open door saying something along the lines of, "so needy." I was wondering if anything like it had come up in previous Harry Potter/Fantastic Beasts lore.

Comment: Pet? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/198975/79913

Answer (score 13):

## Grindelwald’s pet is a baby Chupacapra, named Antonio.

Grindelwald’s pet that’s in his prison cell with him is a baby Chupacabra, a creature that’s described in the screenplay as part lizard, part homunculus and native to the Americas.

> *A baby Chupacabra—part lizard, part homunculus, a blood-sucking creature of the Americas—is chained to GRINDELWALD’S chair.* 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

It’s shown here in Grindelwald’s hands.

[image]

Grindelwald also does throw it through the door of his carriage after saying “so needy”.

> *GRINDELWALD rips the little Chupacabra off SPIELMAN. It rubs its bloody face affectionately against his hand.*
>
> **GRINDELWALD** 
>   
> I know. Okay. I know, Antonio.
>
> *He looks at it with distaste.*
>
> **GRINDELWALD** 
>   
> So needy.
>
> *He then flings it through the door.* 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

Chupacabras have never been mentioned previously in the Harry Potter series - Grindelwald’s pet Antonio is the first one to appear and the first one that’s mentioned.

Comment: Critters like that really get my goat!

Comment: @Verdan Ten points to your House for that joke! :)

Comment: Why was it in his cell?

Comment: @Valorum I haven’t a clue, I just know it was.